# $\int e^{-x} \log \log x dx$ - another special integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I came across this integral in some old notes. After several unsuccessful attempts I ran it in [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28exp%28-x%29%2a%20log%20%28log%28x%29%29) and got an interesting result: the antiderivative (closed form) doesn't exist, but the bounded integral (i.e. from $1$ to $\infty$) is a small constant, which is unsurprising given that the integrand is dominated by $e^{-x}$, which decreases much slower that $\log \log x$ grows for $x \to \infty$.

So I wonder if this integral is known as another 'special' one like the error function $\text{Erf} (x)$. Also, does it have special representations like Legendre Polynomials and estimates of order? It seems to be $O(1)$, but that's just a guess...

Comment: The value of the integral is approximately $-0.330101899149592697696$

The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/index) does not find a match for it, so I doubt there is a well-known constant which has that value.

Comment: It's also $$\int \frac{\ln \ln \ln t}{t^2}dt$$ Where could this integral possibly come from?